# Formatting a number to scientific notation and saving it without surrounding quotes

Tags: python, json, format, quotes, scientific-notation

Is it possible to write a number in scientific format into a json file without surrounding quotes?

I'm using `json.dump` to save the file.

Everything I've tried resulted in double quotes around the number.

```
number = 1234.5678
"{:e}".format(number) -> "1.234568e+03"
"%e" % number -> "1.234568e+03"
f"{d:.4e}" -> "1.2346e+03"
```

The desired output would be: `1.234568e+03`

Comment: What you have shown *must* result in double quotes around the number because they are all ways to convert a number to a *string*.

Comment: Why does the JSON file have to contain the number in scientific notation, instead of any other notation?